# Does .Net Core 3.1 have the InheritedExportAttribute?

Tags: .net-core, mef

My feeling - no, it does not have it. But I want to make sure before I refactor the respective net472 code to be compliant.

Comment: You can see it doesn't if you try to go to the page where it would be: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.inheritedexportattribute?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1

Comment: I have been there, but I do not know what .NET Platform Extensions are and whether they are compatible with .Net Core or not. I suppose I could have googled it.